# How to generate a static html file from a swagger documentation?

Tags: linux, swagger, api-doc, html-generation

I have created a Swagger documentation with a `yaml` file under:

```
api/swagger/swagger.yaml
```

Now I want to share a static HTML document with its definition, yet it was stated on the [swagger project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/664#issuecomment-209228699), that they don't plan to support HTML generation at all.

How can I generate a static HTML file from a Swagger project?

Answer (score 26):

The easiest way I can think of is to use [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io):

1. Go to: https://editor.swagger.io
2. Click on "File" in the top menu bar and then select "Import File"
3. After import, click on "Generate Client" in the top menu bar, and then select "HTML" or "HTML2" to generate static HTML documentation

editor.swagger.io uses generator.swagger.io to generate API clients, server stubs and documentation, and generator.swagger.io is powered by the open-source project [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen).

Comment: The generated html/html2 documentation is pretty bad at handling `GET` query parameters...

Comment: The latest supported version at that link is 3.0. This is a problem because my API generates a 3.1 schema. But on that page they link to the new version, which does support 3.1. Here it is: https://editor-next.swagger.io

Answer (score 14):

1. Download https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui - folder of interest is "[dist](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist)"
2. Copy your Swagger JSON into the dist folder
3. Open index.html and change the value of URL inside the  tag at the bottom of the file to `./swagger.json` (or whatever your swagger json is called) (see [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html#L42))
4. Host online! (or start a local server to view output).

Answer (score 4):

There is [swagger2markup-cli](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup-cli) that can generate a static `adoc` file.

Ensure that you have Java runtime installed. (I am using `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)`).

You fetch the jar:

```
wget https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/github/swagger2markup/swagger2markup-cli/1.1.0/swagger2markup-cli-1.1.0.jar
```

And you can generate the a static `adoc` with it via:

```
java -jar ~/your/path/swagger2markup-cli-1.1.0.jar convert  -i api/swagger/swagger.yaml --outputFile static-swagger
```

That adoc file can then be converted into a `html` file via [`asciidoctor`](http://asciidoctor.org/):

```
asciidoctor *.adoc
```

You may need to install it, as I am using Ubuntu, I could via:

```
sudo apt-get -qq install asciidoctor
```

Comment: This solution works for me, just a few notes: the generated pages are not hyperlinked, they're just simple HTML pages with no frames. asciidoctor is Ruby dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to export it to create single documentation from different services? If yes, an alternative might be https://github.com/varghgeorge/microservices-single-swagger. This simple springboot microservice will show all your swagger documentation (from different servers) in one place based on YAML config.

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTML file like this to load your OpenAPI definition:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css">

  <title>Your App API v1</title>

<body>

  <div id="your-app-docs" />

  <script src="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
  <script>

    window.onload = function () {

      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "openapi.yml",
        dom_id: "#your-app-docs",
        deepLinking: true,
      })

    }

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can then later host it locally or use a service like Netlify to host it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer suggested the [`Swagger Editor`](https://editor.swagger.io/)
, which is great. However, to obtain a single file to import into it:

1. `npm install -g @apidevtools/swagger-cli`
2. `swagger-cli bundle openapi.yaml --outfile ./openapi-expanded.json --type json`

The above command assumes your root file is named `openapi.yaml` and you want an output JSON file `openapi-expanded.json`: that JSON is what you'll import.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried redocly, and it's pretty neat!
Command with docker:
`docker run --rm -v $PWD:/spec redocly/cli build-docs <your_swagger.yaml>`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redocly/cli