# How to export swagger "Try it out" HTML forms?

Tags: html, forms, swagger

I want to export HTML web forms created in swagger UI on "Try it out" click. How to export all forms to separate files?

Comment: do you like to win easy ;)

Comment: @alessandro: it really makes me wonder why all swagger-generate projects do not provide simple export vanilla HTML forms options...

Comment: maybe something like this https://github.com/bootprint/bootprint-monorepo/tree/master/packages/bootprint-openapi

Comment: @alessandro: it generates a page worse than swagger-generate html2. And that page does not contain any forms.

Comment: Do these links answer your question? [How to generate a static html file from a swagger documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40407112/113116), [Generate static docs with swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26605217/113116), [Is it possible to get an offline version of Swagger documentation for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50137466/113116), [Swagger single interactive HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45567723/113116)